# How is this character written: “一点一横长，二字下来口字方，两边丝绕绕，中间马大王，你也长，我也长，心字底，月字旁，打把金钩挂衣裳。”

Tags: characters

《广安方言与民俗词典》has the following entry:

> 【biáng】
>
> 普通话中无“b-i-ang”发音，属于群众自创方音。象声词，本义指用力扯面中面条击打案板之声。生活中常作为口语化的象声词，如巴掌打在脸上的声音、面积较大的东西摔在地上的声音等。为了方便记忆，民间还有此字歌谣：“一点一横长，二字下来口字方，两边丝绕绕，中间马大王，你也长，我也长，心字底，月字旁，打把金钩挂衣裳。”

What character is `“一点一横长，二字下来口字方，两边丝绕绕，中间马大王，你也长，我也长，心字底，月字旁，打把金钩挂衣裳。”` exactly?

I get kind of lost after 二字下来口字方.

Comment: https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biángbiáng面 Welcome to Xi'an to taste this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must mean this:

[image: biang],

this word simulates many things which I can't tell you guys in English

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for sure, but I think this must be [biáng](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%BF%BA%E8%BE%B6%E2%BF%B3%E7%A9%B4%E2%BF%B2%E6%9C%88%E2%BF%B1%E2%BF%B2%E5%B9%BA%E8%A8%80%E5%B9%BA%E2%BF%B2%E9%95%B7%E9%A6%AC%E9%95%B7%E5%88%82%E5%BF%83) as seen at Wiktionary.  I saw it recently in an article about a teacher punishing students who were late to class.

I see the "马" in the middle, and your description mentions "心字", also "丝", also "长", also "月"... This must be it!

[This](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:Bi%C3%A1ng.svg) is a big picture of the biáng character I'm talking about.  I lost count after 50 strokes...  :)  More pictures at [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Bi%C3%A1ng_(Chinese_character_for_noodle)).  That's lot of strokes for 'noodles'!